# Out of Memory Error when pushing to Cloud Foundry

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I try to push my app to Cloud Foundry, but get this error:

```
Staging failed: Exited with status 223 (out of memory)
```

This happens while resolving the `requirements.txt`.

Here is some stacktrace:

```
/tmp/buildpacks/555e1c5491df8298a7d2ee82e346f99b/bin/steps/pip-install: line 25:   122 Killed                  /app/.cloudfoundry/python/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt --exists-action=w --src=/app/.cloudfoundry/src
   123 Done                    | cleanup
   124 Done                    | indent
Failed to compile droplet
Exit status 223
Staging failed: Exited with status 223 (out of memory)
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container
```

What I tried so far is to set the environment variable unmask to 0022, because a similiar error with the java buildpack could be resolved this way.

Any help is very much appreciated, let me know, if you need further info.

Comment: How did you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is failing to stage.  It looks like the platform is killing `pip` because it's exceeding the memory limit assigned to the staging container.  Staging containers are given a memory limit of either 1G or the memory limit you assign your application, whichever one is larger.

Given this, my suggestion to resolve this would be to increase the memory limit for your app above 1G, maybe try 2G, and see if `pip` is able to complete.  Once staging completes, you can run `cf scale -m` and reduce the memory usage for your app, if your application does not need that much memory.

Other possible solutions:

1. Run `pip` locally and ["vendor"](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring) your dependencies.  You can then push the dependencies up with the application which might reduce `pip`'s memory consumption.
2. Investigate why `pip` is consuming so much memory and attempt to reduce its memory usage.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I had my virtual enviroment (created using virtualenv package) part of the folder I was deploying to PCF. Adding that to `.cfignore` ignores the virtual environment folder.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you don't have enough memory in org to push an app to cloud foundry. You can free memory in org by deleting unused apps.